# Login to AWS console with an account and to IAM on another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a freelance dev, and I work a lot from my EC2 instances. Now I also have to manage instances for other people, and I find quite a pain to logout/login again to switch consoles.

Is there a way I can access both my personal AWS console and the ones I login through IAM? I don't mind using 2 tabs, having them in one single console being the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to do this is to use different browsers. Obviously this doesn't scale well, but will handle 2 accounts.

Using the latest AWS CLI tools, you can use multiple profiles and specify the profile as a parameter, so that might be a better way to manage your infrastructure.